# How to invalidate ViewModel/LiveData after some time?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

As recommended by the latest documentation I'm using ViewModel/LiveData to show some data:

```java
public class EventDatesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<String> timeToEvent = new MutableLiveData<>();

    ...

    public LiveData<String> getTimeToEvent() {
        if (timeToEvent == null)
            new Thread(this::calculateTimeToEvent).start();
        return timeToEvent;
    }

    private void calculateTimeToEvent() {

        ...

        timeToEvent.postValue(t);
    }
}
```

I use that in my fragment:

```java
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_garbage, container, false);

        EventDatesViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(requireActivity().getApplication())).get(EventDatesViewModel.class);
        model.getTimeToEvent().observe(this, timeToEvent -> {
            ((TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.textTimeToEvent)).setText(timeToEvent);
        });
        return root;
    }
```

Now the problem is that `timeToEvent` is something like "2 days 4 hours". So if I leave the app open, at some point it will be outdated and needs to be recalculated. If the app is not open or is in the background, I don't want to run the rather expensive calculation.

How can I achieve this periodical recalculation?

---

##### What didn't work

I added a Handler that uses `postDelayed()` to schedule the recalculation.

```java
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Thread(() -> calculateTimeToEvent()).start();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    };
```

```java
 public LiveData<String> getTimeToEvent() {
        if (timeToEvent == null) {
            new Thread(this::calculateTimeToEvent).start();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
        }
        return timeToEvent;
    }
```

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        super.onCleared();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
```

Unfortunately this runs the calculation even when the app is in the background or the device is sleeping. I logged the runs of `calculateTimeToEvent()` with timestamps into a file and I can see that they occur every 10 seconds, with no interruption.

Comment: Are you asking how to schedule a recurring operation every `2 days 4 hours`?

Comment: @tyczj I'm asking how to schedule a recurring operation every hour or so in a way that it **has access to the ViewModel** to post a new value and only runs if the ViewModel is actually currently used.

Comment: 1.) why are you using ` new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(requireActivity().getApplication()))` explicitly? Fragment already has a default view model provider factory that has better behavior 2.) why are you using `this` as LifecycleOwner instead of `getViewLifecycleOwner()`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce 1) In my ViewModel I need a `Context` to show toasts, so it's an `AndroidViewModel` and that was the shortest code I could find that can instantiate an `AndroidViewModel`. 2) I copied that code from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) but it seems I mixed up the two examples.

Comment: I didn't ask "why is it an AndroidViewModel", I asked why it is `new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(requireActivity().getApplication()))`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce How *else* would I instantiate an AndroidViewModel?

Comment: just use the default by not passing in a custom factory

Comment: @EpicPandaForce You mean `new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(EventDatesViewModel.class)`? Then I get `Cannot create an instance of class [...] EventDatesViewModel [...] Caused by: [...] EventDatesViewModel has no zero argument constructor`.

Comment: @AndreKR that means you have a version mismatch and should update your `activity` and `fragment` dependencies in Gradle

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have no idea what that means, I let Android Studio manage the project and I just set it up two weeks ago. It's derived from the "Tabbed Activity" template.

Comment: It means you need to update the androidx activity and androidx fragment dependencies

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Indeed, after updating appcompat to 1.3.1 (from 1.2.0) the default factory works *and* it somehow triggered a lint that I should use `getViewLifecycleOwner()` instead of `this`, just like you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Java you can use a Handler using `postDelayed` to fire a runnable after X amount of time then schedule it again after it fires

This is kotlin but can easily be turned back into Java

In your ViewModel

```
private val _handler = Handler()

private val _runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        calculateTimeToEvent()
        _handler.postDelayed(this, 3600000)
    }

}
```

Then at some point call this in your viewmodel to start the recurring operation

```
_handler.postDelayed(_runnable, 3600000)
```

Then in your viewmodel's on `onCleared` you can remove the callbacks to stop it

```
_handler.removeCallbacks(_runnable)
```

There is also the option of Using RxJava and using `interval`

Comment: This `postDelayed` is automatically suspended when the view is not shown? Like when the user has another app open or the phone screen is off?

Comment: Since the activity is no longer around the ViewModel is then no longer needed so onCleared (where you call `removeCallbacks`)  is called stopping the recurring operation

Comment: @AndreKR then that means the ViewModel is still being used ie. activity still in a state where it can be resumed. You can always create a method in your ViewModel to cancel the callbacks from your activity in onPause for example where the activity is no longer active (paused) but not destroyed

Comment: Then why not simply have the fragment call a refresh method on the ViewModel? But I feel like I should be using that LifecycleOwner/Observer stuff?

Comment: You certainly could but you said that you wanted to have it work while the ViewModel is active. Since on a configuration change such as a screen rotation the activity/fragment will cancel/restart the timers since they get recreated unlike ViewModel objects are retained along with their data on a config change so a 1 hour timer could turn into a 2 hour timer theoretically